# Selecting rows with row means greater than the overall mean of a data frame

Tags: r, filter, row, mean

Can we do this thing without `dplyr`? I want to select those rows which have their rowmeans greater than the overall mean of the dataframe.

I have tried to use the function but it does not work.

```
tf12 <- apply(tf11, 2, function(x) filter(rowMeans(x) > mean(x)))
```

It gives the following error.

```
Error in rowMeans(x) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `unlist` to calculate `mean` of entire dataframe and then compare it with `rowMeans`

```
tf11[rowMeans(tf11) > mean(unlist(tf11)), ]
```

Use `na.rm = TRUE` in `mean` and `rowMeans` if you have `NA` values in the dataframe.

Consider an example,

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
df[rowMeans(df) > mean(unlist(df)), ]

#    a  b
#6   6 16
#7   7 17
#8   8 18
#9   9 19
#10 10 20
```

Comment: If I have to iterate the same condition till my row count is <= to 20 where my dataframe let's say has 200 rows. Then, how can we convert above line from @RonakShah into a function?

Comment: @ambrishdhaka you could do separately but I guess adding another condition wouldn't be too confusing. `tf11[rowMeans(tf11) > mean(unlist(tf11)) & seq_len(nrow(tf11)) <= 20, ]`

Comment: I have an observation @Ronak Shah, running single line command 2-times produces much-desired result than the second command carrying `seq_len` as the number of rows gets reduced much more than needed; here 20.